# How do I flip sprites horizontally in cocos2d for iphone

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I only know rotation property of CCNode may have something to do with it. But I want to flip a sprite horizontally, not rotated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you mean you would like to horizontally flip a `CCNode`, you simply do:

```
sprite.scaleX *= -1;
```

(or: `sprite.scaleX = -sprite.scaleX`); if your sprite is not scaled at all in the first place, you might do simply:

```
sprite.scaleX = -1;
```

The `CCSprite` class has got a `flipX`/`flipY` methods that may serve your purpose. Keep in mind the following [difference in behaviour](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-objc/blob/v3.5.0/cocos2d/CCSprite.h), though:

> @note Flipping does not flip any of the sprite's child sprites nor does it alter the anchorPoint.
>
> If that is what you want, you should try inversing the CCNode scaleX property: `sprite.scaleX *= -1.0;`.

Comment: glad it helped. don't forget to accept the answer if its proposed solution worked...

Comment: @simple-thomas: sorry, but my answer is neither outdated nor incorrect. `scaleX` is a perfectly accepted way of flipping (see my amended answer) depending on the kind of result you want. In any case, the OP mentioned `CCNode` and that should rule out using `flipX` -- nevertheless, I added a mention to that method for `CCSprite`s. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer is wrong (or outdated). What you actually should use is:

```
sprite.flipX=YES;
```

and

```
sprite.flipX=NO;
```

to reverse it

Comment: Note that sergio's answer works well for a Node, which doesn't have a flip method.

Comment: @TigerCoding: thanks -- it is also true that `scaleX` is a perfectly accepted way of flipping (see my amended answer) depending on the kind of result you want.

Answer (score 1):

YOU CAN TRY THIS :

```
CCSprite* heroSprite = (CCSprite*) _character.children[0];
```

Then use heroSprite for example :

```
    heroSprite.flipX = YES;
```

It work for node .

Answer (score 1):

In the current version cocos2d-js (3.8) :
Try,

```
sprite.flippedX = true; //for flipping horizontally.
sprite.flippedY = true; //for flipping vertically.
```